# confused about streams

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, operating-system

I am running a command in windows like :

`command.exe > file.txt`

and I get a text in the file, but when I run `command.exe` directly it does not shows that text on the console. The command should have outputted to `stdout`, but it didn't. Is there a way I can find out which stream the text goes to and read that text using `php`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why did you tag this question PHP? command.exe is an executable and the rest is standard windows 'streaming'.

Comment: There are 2 ways mainly to run commands in php, one does auto dump to output, the second would store it in a string..

Comment: Erwin, because hes calling the system command or exec and wants to process the results.

Comment: @BugFinder what are those 2 ways

Comment: See above - How about you bother to show your code? if you look on the manual it will tell you the alternatives and how to use them and get responses

Comment: @BugFinder I dont have a code yet..

Comment: Then how did you establish it didnt show the text on the console?

Comment: @BugFinder command.exe was run both times using a simple command prompt and now I want to do that using php while also getting that text

Comment: If the command doesnt out put anything then theres no way to make php to pick up invisible information, unless it wrote to stderror

Comment: @BugFinder how is that command able to redirect that text in a file then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running shell commands in PHP is like calling [shell_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) or any of the linked functions there. The output of the command goes to where the doc says.

For example passthru() sends the output directly to the browser.

Comment: is there any explanation to this. I mean the redirection operator is able to get text in a file, but without a redirection text is not shown on the console..

Comment: You can always try to redirect STDOUT and STDERR to a target of your choice. It depends on your command.

Comment: Another thing might be that your command explicitly does not output to STDOUT if it detects this.

Comment: Thanks for your time..it is returned using exec()..I decompiled the binary, the command uses a simple wprintf..no stdout detection..didnt found out how its hiding the text from console..still got what i needed